# Exceptional divisor of blowing up $\mathbb A^2$ twice

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\pi:\tilde X\to X$ denote the blow up of $X = {\rm Bl}_0\mathbb A^2$ at a point $p$ in the exceptional divisor $E$ of $X$ and let $E'$ denote the exceptional divisor of $\tilde X$. Now, I am wondering if $(E')^2=-1$ again by the same reasoning for $E^2=-1$, i.e., taking an irreducible curve passing through $p$ (in this case only $E$?) and observing $\pi^*E\sim \tilde E + E'$, $E'\cdot \pi^*E= 0$, and $E'\cdot \tilde E=1$, where $\tilde E$ is the binational transform of $E$. Is this result essentially due to the fact that we can choose a point from one of the standard affine chart of $X$ (and not contained in the other) and thus this binational transform is again locally just a blow up of $\mathbb A^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $(E')^2 = -1$, and this is true for the blowup of a point on any smooth surface (or even for the blowup of a smooth point on any surface).